# Display present coordinate Circle instead of all the point using opencv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, mouseevent

I am trying to draw a circle a present coordinate when the mouse moves from one place to another in OpenCV screen

Right now I am able to see all the circle where the mouse has been moved from one place to another as mentioned below in the snap

[image]

But I need to display only one circle(**present coordinate**) while using EVENT_MOUSEMOVE in mouse events as mentioned in snapshot

[image]

mentioned below is my code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math

drawing = False

def draw_circle(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global x1, y1, drawing, radius, num, img, img2
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        drawing = True
        num += 1
        x1, y1 = x, y
        radius = int(math.sqrt((x - x1)**2 + (y - y1)**2))
        print(radius)
        cv2.circle(img, (x1,y1), radius, (255, 0, 0), 1)

    if event == cv2.EVENT_MOUSEMOVE:
        if drawing == True:
            radius = 5
            cv2.circle(img, (x, y), radius, (0, 0, 255), -1)

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONUP:
        #drawing = False
        num += 1
        radius = int(math.sqrt((x - x1)**2 + (y - y1)**2))
        print(radius)
        cv2.circle(img, (x1,y1), radius, (255, 0, 255), 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    num = 0
    windowName = 'Drawing'

    img = np.zeros((500, 500, 3), np.uint8)
    cv2.namedWindow(windowName)
    cv2.setMouseCallback(windowName, draw_circle)
    while (True):
        cv2.imshow(windowName, img)
        if cv2.waitKey(20) == 27:
            break

    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Suggestions will be very helpful

Comment: Your question is not clear to me.

Comment: I updated another image I want to display circle only where mouse pointer is available instead of that no other points

Comment: set all image to black before drawing the new circle